# How to use OpenAI Function Calling API for a product description generator?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, openai-api, chatgpt-api

In a C# MVC app, I am trying to create a module that uses existing product titles/descriptions and through the OpenAI API enhance them.
Right now, for the purposes of my HTML code I am explicitly asking ChatGPT4 to return its answer in JSON with a specific format. More specifically this is its System message:

> Chat.AppendSystemMessage("You are a product description generator. Create a Meta Title, Meta Description, Meta Keywords. Also create an expanded description and a product title. Response must be in JSON and not use arrays and in Greek: {syMetaTitle, syMetaDescription, syKeyWords, syName, syGeneralDescription}");

```
Chat.AppendUserInput(UserPrompt);
```

Then I am handling the response like so:

```
Response = await Chat.GetResponseFromChatbotAsync();
Response = Response.Trim();
responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<syDescribot_Updated>(Response);
```

Which sometimes (maybe one out of twenty) crashes because of GPT's response bad format

I read a little about Function Calling API but I can't understand if it is useful for my use case and if it is how could I implement it in my C# app?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question's title:

1- Make a OpenAI account.
2- Install the OpenAI package:

```
dotnet add package OpenAI
```

3- Import the namespace.

```
using OpenAI;
```

4- Use the API:
*To generate a product description, you'll need to call the API.*

```
var _openAi = new OpenAIClient("YOUR_API_KEY_HERE");
var _response = _openAi.CompletePrompt("Generate a product description for {product_name} that is {product_description_length} characters long.");
var description = _response.Choices[0].Text;
```

5- When you receive the response from the API, you can use the generated product description in your application.